# What does "Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file" mean?

Tags: c++, opengl, compiler-warnings, mingw32

With this environment, I have compiled a c++/openGL example posted online:

1. Windows 7
2. Code::Blocks v 13.12
3. MinGW build Oct 2013 (not sure on version)
4. mingw32-g++ v 4.8.1

The code from [codeincodeblock.com](http://www.codeincodeblock.com/2013/05/beginner-learning-materials-for-modern.html):

```
#define GLEW_STATIC
// third-party libraries
#include <windows.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glfw.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>

#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>


GLuint gVAO = 0;
GLuint gVBO = 0;
GLuint programId;
const glm::vec2 SCREEN_SIZE(800, 600);

static void LoadTriangle() {
    // make and bind the VAO
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &gVAO);
    glBindVertexArray(gVAO);

    // make and bind the VBO
    glGenBuffers(1, &gVBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, gVBO);

    // Put the three triangle verticies into the VBO
    GLfloat vertexData[] = {
        //  X     Y     Z
         0.0f, 0.8f, 0.0f,
        -0.8f,-0.8f, 0.0f,
         0.8f,-0.8f, 0.0f,
    };
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertexData), vertexData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // connect the xyz to the "vert" attribute of the vertex shader
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);

    // unbind the VBO and VAO
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}

// draws a single frame
static void Render() {
    // clear everything
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1); // black
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);



    // bind the VAO (the triangle)
    glBindVertexArray(gVAO);

    // draw the VAO
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

    // unbind the VAO
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    // swap the display buffers (displays what was just drawn)
    glfwSwapBuffers();
}

// the program starts here
void AppMain() {
    // initialise GLFW
    if(!glfwInit())
        throw std::runtime_error("glfwInit failed");

    // open a window with GLFW
    glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
    glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_WINDOW_NO_RESIZE, GL_TRUE);
    if(!glfwOpenWindow((int)SCREEN_SIZE.x, (int)SCREEN_SIZE.y, 8, 8, 8, 8, 0, 0, GLFW_WINDOW))
        throw std::runtime_error("glfwOpenWindow failed. Can your hardware handle OpenGL 3.2?");

    // initialise GLEW
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE; //stops glew crashing on OSX :-/
    if(glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
        throw std::runtime_error("glewInit failed");

    // print out some info about the graphics drivers
    std::cout << "OpenGL version: " << glGetString(GL_VERSION) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "GLSL version: " << glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Vendor: " << glGetString(GL_VENDOR) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Renderer: " << glGetString(GL_RENDERER) << std::endl;

    // make sure OpenGL version 3.2 API is available
    if(!GLEW_VERSION_3_2)
        throw std::runtime_error("OpenGL 3.2 API is not available.");

    // create buffer and fill it with the points of the triangle
    LoadTriangle();

    // run while the window is open
    while(glfwGetWindowParam(GLFW_OPENED)){
        // draw one frame
        Render();
    }

    // clean up and exit
    glfwTerminate();
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    try {
        AppMain();
    } catch (const std::exception& e){
        std::cerr << "ERROR: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The altered version I made to work with glfw3:

```
#define GLEW_STATIC
// third-party libraries
#include <windows.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glfw3.h>  // --- changed
#include <glm/glm.hpp>

#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>


GLuint gVAO = 0;
GLuint gVBO = 0;
GLuint programId;
const glm::vec2 SCREEN_SIZE(800, 600);
GLFWwindow *window;  // --- added

static void LoadTriangle() {
    // make and bind the VAO
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &gVAO);
    glBindVertexArray(gVAO);

    // make and bind the VBO
    glGenBuffers(1, &gVBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, gVBO);

    // Put the three triangle verticies into the VBO
    GLfloat vertexData[] = {
        //  X     Y     Z
         0.0f, 0.8f, 0.0f,
        -0.8f,-0.8f, 0.0f,
         0.8f,-0.8f, 0.0f,
    };
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertexData), vertexData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // connect the xyz to the "vert" attribute of the vertex shader
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);

    // unbind the VBO and VAO
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}

// draws a single frame
static void Render(GLFWwindow *win) {  // --- changed
    // clear everything
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1); // black
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);



    // bind the VAO (the triangle)
    glBindVertexArray(gVAO);

    // draw the VAO
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

    // unbind the VAO
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    // swap the display buffers (displays what was just drawn)
    glfwSwapBuffers(win);  // --- changed
}

// the program starts here
void AppMain() {
    // initialise GLFW
    if(!glfwInit())
        throw std::runtime_error("glfwInit failed");

    // open a window with GLFW
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);  // --- changed
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);  // --- changed
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VERSION_MINOR, 2);  // --- changed
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_TRUE);  // --- changed

    window = glfwCreateWindow((int)SCREEN_SIZE.x, (int)SCREEN_SIZE.y,"Test window",0,0);  // --- changed

    if(window == NULL)
        throw std::runtime_error("glfwOpenWindow failed. Can your hardware handle OpenGL 3.2?");

    // initialise GLEWuj
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE; //stops glew crashing on OSX :-/
    if(glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
        throw std::runtime_error("glewInit failed");

    // print out some info about the graphics drivers
    std::cout << "OpenGL version: " << glGetString(GL_VERSION) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "GLSL version: " << glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Vendor: " << glGetString(GL_VENDOR) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Renderer: " << glGetString(GL_RENDERER) << std::endl;

    // make sure OpenGL version 3.2 API is available
    if(!GLEW_VERSION_3_2)
        throw std::runtime_error("OpenGL 3.2 API is not available.");

    // create buffer and fill it with the points of the triangle
    LoadTriangle();

    // run while the window is open
    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)){  // --- changed
        // draw one frame
        Render(window);  // --- changed
    }

    // clean up and exit
    glfwTerminate();
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    try {
        AppMain();
    } catch (const std::exception& e){
        std::cerr << "ERROR: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I added -mwindows to the linker options and otherwise set up my openGL environment as per Dinesh's instructions on his [Setup Modern OpenGL page](http://www.codeincodeblock.com/2013/05/setup-modern-opengl-3-and-4-with-glfw.html).

Note please that Dinesh uses an earlier glfw build and as such prompted me to make the changes to get the code to compile and execute.

At any rate, the build produces this output:

```
=== Build: Debug in OpenGLTest (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
=== Build finished: 0 error(s), 1 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 5 second(s)) ===
=== Run: Debug in OpenGLTest (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===
```

So my question(s) after all of that is: what does the warning mean and should I be concerned?

Answer (score 0):

When I ran into this problem it was because I was linking against incompatible MSVC libs. A comment by keltar helped me through this problem.

[SDL 2.0: linking error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23240158/sdl-2-0-linking-error)

Comment: Thanks!  I looked at it and worked a bit on what I had, but it has been a month and I have slept so many times since then, I forgot what changes I made to try and get this to work.  Figures.  But, the next time I try, I will start over from scratch and get it working.