# Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file

Tags: opengl, eclipse-cdt, glfw, glew

I installed glew, glfw and glm in eclipse cdt(c++) with the gcc/mingw, all statically.
All works fine, but I don't like the warning in the output console of eclipse:

> Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file

How I can fix and hide this warning ?
What does it mean ?

And what I noticed is, that this warning comes only, if I call the 'glewInit' function.

Answer (score 11):

When I ran into this problem it was because I was linking against incompatible MSVC libs.  A comment by keltar helped me through this problem.

[SDL 2.0: linking error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23240158/sdl-2-0-linking-error)

Answer (score 9):

The message

> Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file

could also mean, that the project is being built with **MinGW** but the library it uses is created for **Visual Studio**.

MinGW and Visual Studio builds are not interchangeable.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error in CLion for MinGW toolchain, but when I switched to VisualStudio toolchain, it disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

For me the reason this error came up was this:

I was building my project with mingw g++
BUT I was building the library with visual studio

different compilers use different .lib, .a, etc files

SO my solution:

1. I generated glfw files with cmake for MSys2 Makefiles (I had make installed via msys2)
2. Built that by going into the folder with the generated files and ran `make`
3. Renamed "libglfw3.a" to "glfw3.lib" and moved it to my library directory

Then using the flag `-L"{folder that glfw3.lib is in}" -lglfw3` in g++ it compiled just fine