# SDL error: ld returned 1 exit status and no errors displayed

Tags: c++, sdl

This is, I think, a complex problem I'm having. I'm just trying to set up a basic SDL project, I'm actually following this tutorial: 
http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/01_hello_SDL/index2.php

Here is the full build log.

```
||=== Build: Debug in Drekirokr (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
||Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file|
||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 1 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

As you can see, it trows me there is an error, but there is nothing as far as I can understand. Of course the **ld returned 1 exit status** is an error, but I've searched for the line elsewhere, and it always has some other error, like a typo in a class name reference or something, and for them I think things get solved by solving that other error.
The other line, **corrupt .drective at end of def file**, people having this log seem to be able to compile just fine. In my case, I can't. I've tried compiling anything else, and I've successfully compiled a "hello world" that uses only stdio.h for printf.

Here is my code

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char* args[] ) {
    return 0;
}
```

I've added the search directories and the linker options. I just can't figure what's wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your build system? To solve this problem, your build system file may be required, be it an IDE project file or a makefile or cmake etc.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23240158/sdl-2-0-linking-error Also, I highly encourage you to do development in an OS which was built for it, namely Linux, where you can install the compiler and SDL with a single command and have no compatibility issues like this one.

Comment: Yes, that link solved my problem. Didn't read properly the instructions at the tutorial, actual Mingw libraries and headers are in the i686-w64-mingw32 (for 32bit). I really thank you for your help @iksemyonov and the people responding at the linked question. This question is answered!

Comment: @iksemyonov SDL works just fine with Visual Studio. But yeah, MinGW and/or Cygwin can be a pain.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I tried your code, it worked for me.
Than I put the code just into one main.cpp file (so no project), and 
  ld returned 1 exit status, too.

So try to put your code into a project file! That should solve it

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @iksemyonov, found the answer here.
[SDL 2.0: linking error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23240158/sdl-2-0-linking-error)

Problem was that the actual Mingw libraries, headers and binaries are found at the i686-w64-mingw32 folder.
Libs for instance are not at lib/x86. Those are for MSVC.

I actually wonder why the Mingw32 download not only includes the MSVC files, but also gets obscured by it (in my opinion, of course).

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Glad the suggestion helped. You can accept your own answer to indicate that the solution worked and the problem is now solved.